# If two checkboxes are checked do this not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is check if the first check box is selected and then after that the second box is selected if that happens I want to do something. This is what I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: To start with there's a syntax error in your console. Open it (F12).

Comment: use this `$("#anchor-from").change(function(){
                $('#period-daily').is(':checked') {
                    console.log(finalStartDDIDate1);
                }
                else if($('#period-weekly').is(':checked')) {
                    console.log(finalEndDDIDate1);
                }
});`

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava If you have the answer please post it as an answer. Comparing differences between your code and the OP's when its not formatted in a comment is quite difficult.

Comment: replicate your problem on fiddle

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML, see the "[MCVE]" guidelines for explanation.

Comment: what is this #anchor-from? Is it checkbox or radio buton or anchor tag?Is this added dynamically?

Comment: you code and your explanation does not match

Comment: @AkashKumar, Are you looking for this: https://jsfiddle.net/9g56gm8z/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

## [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Suganth745/9g56gm8z/1/)

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="anchor-from"/>CheckBox1

<input type="checkbox" id="period-daily"/>period
<input type="checkbox" id="period-weekly"/>week
```

JS:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){

                if($('#anchor-from').is(':checked') && $('#period-daily').is(':checked')) {
                    alert("peroid");
                }
                else if($('#anchor-from').is(':checked') && $('#period-weekly').is(':checked')) {
                    alert("weekly");
                }
            });
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Check my Demo I think you want like this **[DEMO CLICK](https://jsfiddle.net/9g56gm8z/5/)**

Only one checkbox can be used at a time .

> Click on checkbox 2 to choose it ... if you want to change the
>   selection ... uncheck the checkbox 2 than only you can select checkbox
>   3 .....Its with validation in a sense

.

```
$("#anchor-from").change(function(){
                if($('#anchor-from').is(':checked'))
                {
                  $("#period-daily").attr("disabled", false); 
                  $("#period-weekly").attr("disabled", false); 
                }
                else
                {
                $("#period-weekly").attr("disabled", true); 
                 $("#period-daily").attr("disabled", true); 
                }



            });

        $("#period-daily").change(function(){
           if($('#period-daily').is(':checked')) {
                  $("#period-weekly").attr("disabled", true); 
                    alert("do something here daily");
                }else
                {
                 $("#period-weekly").attr("disabled", false); 
                }
                });

                $("#period-weekly").change(function(){
           if($('#period-weekly').is(':checked')) {
                  $("#period-daily").attr("disabled", true); 
                    alert("do something here weekly");
                }else

                {
                $("#period-daily").attr("disabled", false); 

                }
                });
```

Comment: @AkashKumar : Nice to hear that

Answer (score -2):

Syntax error

change your code to
 `$("#anchor-from").change(function(){
                if($('#period-daily').is(':checked')){
                    console.log(finalStartDDIDate1);
                }
                else if($('#period-weekly').is(':checked')) {
                    console.log(finalEndDDIDate1);
                }
});`

Answer (score -2):

```
$("#anchor-from").change(function(){
if($("#anchor-from").(is)(':checked')){
                if($('#period-daily').(is)(':checked')) {
                    console.log(final1);
                }
                else if($('#period-weekly').is(':checked')) {
                    console.log(final2);
                }
}
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

try this way.

```
$("#anchor-from").on('change',function(){
            if($('#period-daily').prop(':checked')) {
                console.log(final1);
            }
            else if($('#period-weekly').prop(':checked')) {
                console.log(final2);
            }
        });
```

Comment: More explanation please.

Comment: either  do `.prop( "checked" )` OR  `.is(":checked")`